# Synchronizing 3 servers over IP

Tags: webserver, sync

I'm setting up a medical server for a hospital that has doctors located in 3 different locations, meaning there would be 3 servers (1 in each location). All 3 servers would just have the following software:

```
Ubuntu Server 12.04 minimal
MySQL, PHP 5, Apache
The medical software which would read/write to the MySQL database
Remote admin apps like Nagios & Webmin
Rsync for backup (rsync-over-ssh) as a cron job
```

and the doctors at each location would access patient & billing data from their respective servers.

What I'd like is, that each of these servers all have synchronized info (especially the mySQL database's) - let's say on an hourly basis each of these servers synchronize data to a common remote server and the data is then brought down to each of the servers.

I know an easier way would be to have the medical app running on a remote web server, but since this is medical that we're talking about and knowing how common it is in our area for the net to go gown, I wouldn't like a web based scenatio.

Is such a setup possible?
Would this be the right way to do things or is there a better way to this?

Would really appreciate views and comments (or how to set this up) on this.

Answer (score -1):

For your mysql databases take a look at this:

https://www.percona.com/software/mysql-database/percona-xtradb-cluster

**Percona XtraDB Cluster with Galera on Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS 3 nodes**

**Percona XtraDB Cluster** is a high availability and high scalability solution for **MySQL** users. XtraDB Cluster integrates Percona Server with the Galera library of high availability solutions in a single product package. XtraDB Cluster enables users to save money through:

Less downtime and higher availability

Reduced investment in high availability architectures

Lower DBA training and education costs

No investment in third-party, high availability solutions

---

For **HA** (High Availability) solutions see

**Heartbeat**

**Pacemaker**

**Corosync**

**DRBD**

Comment: Thanks, ptheo.Would an HA cluster be a pretty complicated setup and still depend alot on a reliable internet connection since the servers (or node's in this case) are in different locations?(pls correct me if I'm wrong).I'm looking at something similar to what I've drawn at http://i49.tinypic.com/2lm0xnq.png So maybe on an hourly basis there's a cron-job doing an rsync-over-ssh to the server in the data center and then it's brought down to each node.Each doctor at each site will have a different mySQL database dedicated to his practice,but at the end of it all, all 3 servers have the same data